# Projectile delay in shooting c# game

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a game where I want the player to be able to shoot a laser with a delay on it. The code works but I'm wondering if I am going the right way about doing this.

I was wondering what is the proper way to add the delay?

I tried to include the code relevant to the question.

```
private double laserDelay;
private TimeSpan laserShootInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
laserDelay = laserShootInterval.TotalSeconds;

if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
{
    if(laserDelay == laserShootInterval.TotalSeconds)
    { 
          Shoot();
          laserDelay = laserDelay - laserShootInterval.TotalSeconds;
    }

}

UpdateLasers(graphics);


if(laserDelay < laserShootInterval.TotalSeconds)
{
      laserDelay++;
}
```

Comment: A delay on what? The next time it fires or from pressing the button to actually firing? Are you basing everything off of delta time or fixed amount of ticks per second?

Comment: I want there to be a fixed amount of time from the next time it fires so it runs the same on all computers.

Comment: Are you using Delta Time or is it fixed amount of ticks per second?

Comment: There is nothing wrong except the line should read `laserDelay >= laserShootInterval.TotalSeconds`

Comment: Adding to what @MickyD said, as you are using floating point variables (`double`) don't do direct comparisons, instead test if it is above [or equal] / below [or equal] to or test if the value is close to the target rather than exactly the same (as it is very unlikely to be exactly the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you are not using delta time (fixed amount of ticks per second) I would do it like so:

```
int delay = 6 * ticksPerSecond; // ticks to delay for
int cooldown = 0;

public void loop()
{

    if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
        if(cooldown <= 0)
        { 
              Shoot();
              cooldown = delay
        }

    }

    UpdateLasers(graphics);


    if(cooldown > 0){
          cooldown -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to make it time-based so as to make it independant of fixed or non-fixed Unity modes.  If someone changes the mode it would lead to increased code maintenance

Comment: I am not familiar with Unity and there are no Unity tags on the question so I tried to keep it simple ( see my comments on the question also ). I also agree that it should be time based if possible.

Comment: Quite right.  Pretty sure XNA has a similar thing and besides, everything else in game engine-design is always time based, specifically elapsed time since last frame,  rather than current frame index alternatives.

Comment: @MickyD defiantly does as I have used them, fairly sure its fixed to 30tps by default but you can unlock it if you want to

Comment: Excellent.  +1 for you