# How to Add Delay in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a space shooter game in unity I would love to make it so that you can hold down space and fire bullets (I'm using prefabs) but when I use GetKey.KeyCode.Space in the update method and instantiating the bullets in the fixed update method instead of creating like 1 bullet each 0,1 second(as I would like it to) creates a continuous ray of prefabs.

```
private void Update()
{
    _thrusting = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        _turnDirection = 1f;
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        _turnDirection = -1f;
    } else
    {
        _turnDirection = 0f;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (_thrusting)
    {
        _rigidbody.AddForce(this.transform.up * this._thrustSpeed);
    }

    if (_turnDirection != 0)
    {
        _rigidbody.AddTorque(_turnDirection * _turnSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `TimeSpan` to control shooting *in addition to* spacebar being pressed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Projectile delay in shooting c# game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550034/projectile-delay-in-shooting-c-sharp-game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently out of the house, so I'm doing this from memory on a cellphone. Please excuse any typing or code mistakes; though it should at a minimum give you a proper method:

```
float _lastShotTime;
float _shotDelay = 1; //Adjust this. Default here = shoot every 1 second

//If the difference between last shot time and current time is equal or greater than the shot delay then shoot
void TryShooting(){
    if(Time.time - _lastShotTime >= _shotDelay){
        //Update _lastShotTime
        _lastShotTime = Time.time;
        
        //Shoot
        Shoot();
    }
}

void Shoot(){
    //Your shooting code goes here
}
```